# Programatically changing button text and actions when a modifier key is pressed

Tags: swift, nsbutton

I would like to change the text of an `NSButton` when the <kbd>⌥ Option</kbd> key is pressed - similar to the copy dialog when colliding files are detected on OS X which changes "Keep Both" to "Merge" when the option key is held.

In my case, I would like to change a button with text, say, "delete" to "quit" when I hold the option key. Additionally, its functionality should change in accordance with its title, much like the options in the Copy dialog.

Can this be done programatically in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subscribe using `addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching:)` and detect if option key pressed like this:

```
var optionKeyEventMonitor: Any? // property to store reference to the event monitor

// Add the event monitor
optionKeyEventMonitor = NSEvent.addLocalMonitorForEvents(matching: .flagsChanged) { event in
    if event.modifierFlags.contains(.option) {
        self.button.title = "copy"
        self.button.action = #selector(self.copyButtonClicked(_:))
    } else {
        self.button.title = "delete"
        self.button.action = #selector(self.deleteButtonClicked(_:))
    }  
    return event
}

@IBAction func copyButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    Swift.print("Copy button was clicked!")
}

@IBAction func deleteButtonClicked(_ sender: Any) {
    Swift.print("Delete button was clicked!")
}
```

Remember to remove the event monitor when you are done:

```
deinit {
    if let eventMonitor = optionKeyEventMonitor {
        NSEvent.removeMonitor(eventMonitor)
    }
}
```

If you don't want a separate method called depending on the option key state, you can check modifierFlags when button is clicked instead:

```
@IBAction func buttonClicked(sender: NSButton) {
    if NSEvent.modifierFlags().contains(.option) {
        print("option pressed")
    } else {
        print("option not pressed")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 3 code:

```
func optionKeyDown() -> Bool
{
    return NSEvent.modifierFlags().contains(NSEventModifierFlags.option)
}

if optionKeyDown()
{
    print ("do option code")
}
else
{
    print ("do normal code")
}
```